# array_push using arrays issue

Tags: php, array-push

I am collecting some data using foreach and preg_match, if preg_match is true it will add that element to the array $found, but returns this error:

> PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in upfiles.php line 324

```
$found = array();

    foreach($this->disFunctions as $kkeys => $vvals)
    {            
        if(preg_match('#'.$vvals.'#i', $cFile))
        {                
            array_push($found, $vvals); // LINE 324
        } else {
            $found = ''; 
        }
    } // end foreach

    print_r($found);
```

**EDIT:**

Get the array_push values into my class:

```
public final function filterFile(){

    $disabled_functions = ini_get('disable_functions');

    $disFunctionsNoSpace = str_replace(' ', '', $disabled_functions);

    $disFunctions = explode(',', $disFunctionsNoSpace);

    $this->disFunctions = $disFunctions;

    // get file content of the uploaded file (renamed NOT the temporary)
    $cFile = file_get_contents($this->fileDestination, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);


    $found = array();

    foreach($this->disFunctions as $kkeys => $vvals)
    {            
        if(preg_match('#'.$vvals.'#i', $cFile))
        {                  
            array_push($found, $vvals);

        } 
    } // end foreach

} // end filterFile


$up = new uploadFiles($filename);

$fileterringFile    = $up->filterFile();

print_r($fileterringFile);
var_dump($fileterringFile);
```

Thanks for your usual support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if no match is found, `$found` gets changed to an empty string. what you should do is:

```
$found = array();

foreach($this->disFunctions as $kkeys => $vvals)
{            
    if(preg_match('#'.$vvals.'#i', $cFile))
    {                
        array_push($found, $vvals); // LINE 324
    } 
} // end foreach

print_r($found);
```

simply remove the else.

Also what i would do is simply

```
$found[]=$vvals;
```

no real need for `array_push`

Comment: oh yeah, the $found in else is a string

Comment: I edited my code above, how can I get these values from the array while calling a class?

Comment: that's a new question, and should be asked as one

Comment: Sure, I will ask a new question